# How to add all requirements.txt dependencies to py_library in Bazel BUILD file @rules_python

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, bazel

When using Bazel @rules_python there's is this handy target generator helper [pip_parse](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/1722988cc407b08a4e7770295452076706823f9d/docs/pip.md#pip_parse), which generates library targets for every dependency in `requirements.txt`, which is nice:

```
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

pip_parse(
    name = "pip_deps",
    requirements_lock = ":requirements.txt",
)

load("@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")

install_deps()
```

Is there a way to import all those deps into a `py_library` in one step? Otherwise we essentially duplicate the `requirements.txt` content:

```
load("@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

py_library(
    name = "bar",
    ...
    deps = [
       "//my/other:dep",
       requirement("requests"),  # <----------------- duplicate
       requirement("numpy"),     # <----------------- duplicate 
    ],
)
```

Edit: I found the helper `pip_repositories`, which [can be used as follows](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/3c4ed56db7de85b76d870ffab9852e376197d30f/docs/pip_repository.md#pip_repository):

```
load("@foo//:requirements.bzl", "all_requirements")
py_binary(
    name = "baz",
    ...
    deps = [
       ":foo",
    ] + all_requirements,
)
```

but what is the difference?

Comment: You might have multiple `py_binary()` using different sets of requirements all specified in a `requirements.txt`. So not every `py_binary()` should make use of `all_requirement`.